# MediaWiki: How do you put a period after the heading number?

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

I've been unable to find an answer to the following online.

I've enabled auto-numbered headings in MediaWiki by adding the following to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['numberheadings'] = 1;
```

However, I'd like there to be a period after the heading number, to distinguish it from the heading.

That is, I'd like:

**2. This is a heading**

instead of:

**2 This is a heading**

However, I'd prefer the number *not* to have a period after it in the case of sub-headings.

That is, I'd like:

**2.1 This is a heading**

not:

**2.1. This is a heading**

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: frontend or backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is hardcoded, see [Parser.php](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/master/includes/parser/Parser.php;fa1123a012ad03d75f013d20e8c35175dd0e9397$4651), so you will have to modify it after it is created. Your best shot is probably to use the[ParserSectionCreate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserSectionCreate) hook, or possible [ParserBeforeTidy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserBeforeTidy)

If you want to do it frontend: Loop through all headings with the class `mw-headline-number`, and apply your logic there.

Also note that these changes will only affect users that have enabled the numberheadings features in their settings, or registered after you changed the default setting.

Edit: You might want to check what language your user is viewing your wiki in first, as a trailing dot might not be used with all languages and numeral systems. See [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#Values) for some variants (note how the CJK systems use an east asian comma, `壹、`, and how the ge'ez (Ethiopic) example uses a space,  `፫`)

Comment: Thanks very much, but could you - or anyone else - put this in lay terms? I do research in psychology, and am trying to set-up a MediaWiki site as a platform for my research - I don't have knowledge of code.

Comment: Ok, I am essentially saying that you need to program an extension to do what you want. If you can not do that, well this is a programming site, so I guess you won't get much help here, but maybe check one of the MediaWiki mailing lists?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to achieve this is by editing the wiki page "MediaWiki:Common.css" (connected as admin) and adding the following CSS code:

```css
.mw-headline-number::after {
    content: ".";
}
```

If you want only some header levels, you can use the following: (here for level 2 headers (HTML <h2>), which is traditionnally the first level in wikitext since the title is a level 1 header (HTML <h1>))

```css
h2 .mw-headline-number::after {
    content: ".";
}
```

This will appear only for users who activated their preference "Auto-number headings" but you have activated it by default, so it will work for anybody who keep the preference activated.

Once the change is done, you will have to refresh your browser with F5 or Ctrl-R.

Comment: However, is there a way to now disable the period for sub-headings?! That is, I want '2.1', not '2.1.'.

Comment: It’s quite beautiful, I will probably use it for the wikis where I am -- on MediaWiki, users can customise their own environment on wiki pages "User:PSEUDONYM/common.css".

Comment: If you would like to put the "." also in the TOC you can use
`.toclevel-1 > a > .tocnumber::after {
    content: ".";
}`